# keybd_event not working for some applications

Tags: c++, keyboard-events, sendinput

The `keybd_event` function as well as mouse input function are not functioning for a particular application.
I used the following code:

```
keybd_event(VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);

keybd_event(VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

This is not working in 1 application out of many i tried,but that application is able to take input from the keyboard.
I also tried replacing the 2nd parameter with `MapVirtualKey(VK_LMENU,MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)`.

So, how is the application differentiating between simulated input and real input, and how do i send simulated strokes to the application(Some other c++ library function or some parameter twisting).

Thank You

Comment: You cannot poke keystrokes into an app that runs elevated unless you run elevated as well.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that did it. I ran Visual Studio in admin mode and it started working.